# How to customize Release Notes page in Docusaurus?

Tags: javascript, docusaurus

I want to manage my documentation with versions and Release Notes. So I followed steps [here](https://docusaurus.io/docs/en/versioning).

The default code for the link of Release Note was "" as below.

```html
<a href="">Release Note</a>
```

I changed the codes as below:

```html
<a href="/docs/ReleaseNote">Release Note</a>
```

I added header in `ReleaseNote.md` like below.

```
---
id: ReleaseNote
title: Release Note
---
```

and this is not working. I got "Cannot GET /docs/ReleaseNote" error.

How can I customize Release Note link in `versions.js`?

Thank you in advance.

I've changed the header of ReleaseNote.md as below, but it didn't work.

```
---
id: version-1.0.0-ReleaseNote
title: Release Note
original_id: ReleaseNote
---
```

Comment: Docusaurus maintainer here. Are you saying you want to link the "Release Notes" text in `versions.js` to a custom docs page?

Could you provide a link to your repo if it's public?

Answer (score 1):

Any code within `versions.js` is typical React code and you can just modify it. It seems that you're having trouble finding the path to the new page which you've just created, and that is a separate issue from customizing `versions.js`.